# Define type="color" in Safari

Tags: html

I have a html colorpicker defined in my page. Like this:

```html
<div id="colourSelector" class="row">
  <input id="backgroundcolor" name="backgroundcolor" size="6" maxlength="6"  type="color" style="display: block;">
</div>
```

This runs ok on firefox, chrome, IE,... except for Safari.

Any options?

Comment: Try this: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+color+picker

Comment: Thanks dave. I was looking for something more simple. jscolor is a good option but I'm trying to simplify my code.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Yes. I've seen that before. My question is if there is an html option for Safari.